# How to rewrite a directory to a 404 page?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have a hosting account, which has a website on it. Let's call it: www.example.com
In cPanel, I've set up an Addon domain: www.example2.com, which points to a folder on www.example.com:
 www.example.com/example2

How can I throw a 404 error if someone directly visits www.example.com/example2 ?

I've tried this in my .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^example2(.*) - [R=404,L,NC]
```

But it didn't work. It still shows the index.php of the example2 folder. Both the www.example.com and www.example2.com websites have their own .htaccess file. If I disable the .htaccess file on www.example2.com, the above mentioned redirect works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `/example2/.htaccess` have this rule as first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if host name is not example2 then throw 404
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: This showed a 500 Internal Server Error. Changed the [L,404] part to [L,R=404], and it works. Thank you very much. I'll accept your answer as soon as the 15 minutes is over.

Comment: Okay, I had to slightly modify it to make the www part optional:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.\)?example2\.com [NC]`

Comment: Sorry I made some stupid typos but you spotted them. Glad it worked out.